# Jquery call function dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a following scenario that I have to call a function on a jquery object dynamically. The code looks like this :

```
$('div[class]').each(function(){
    var class=$(this).attr('class');

    // I want to now check if that function with the name of class exists for jquery
    // object. I need help here.
    // if that function exists, i need to apply that function to the enumerated object.
});
```

I want to now check if that function with the name of class exists for jQuery object. I need help here.  If that function exists, I need to apply that function to the enumerated object.

Comment: I can't clearly see your use case here. What are you trying to accomplish? Explain it as in if I do this, then this should happen! If this element has the class `abc` I want the function `abc` to be executed, etc...

Comment: Yes, if the element has class abc then I want abc to be executed on that element if that function exists.

Comment: Exists where, in the global namespace, in jQuery's `jQuery.fn.function_here`? Also, are you sure your elements will have only one class?

Comment: Multiple classes is a different case. I will parse it if I have that scenario. I want to check if it exists in globalspace. 

I have function like this: $.fn.funtion_name()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm writing this of the top of my head so it might not work, but try:

```
if(jQuery.isFunction(jQuery[class]))
     jQuery[class](this);
```

Edit: if the function is a jquery method then try with:

```
 if(jQuery.isFunction(jQuery.fn[class])) {
     jQuery.fn[class](this);
     jQuery(this)[class]();    // alternative call syntax
 }
```

Comment: I think that is pretty close that I was looking for. Thank you